# network always off after boot RHEL CentOS 7

Tags: centos, networking, rhel, network-interface, networkmanager

In RHEL/CentOS 7.6, I somehow messed up the files under `/etc/syconfig/network-scripts`

- After boot the wired network is always off; If I go into settings I can simply turn the blue slider `connect on` and it works fine and it uses the static IPv4 address I set it to however long ago.
- The `connect automatically` checkbox is checked, it seems to have no affect.
- With the network working after manually turning it on, the interface name is something like `ensp0s11` however I do not have a corresponding file `ifcfg-ensp0s11` in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/`.  Does this matter?- Trying to use the gui, all I am successful in doing is manually turning the wired network interface on.  Anything else in that gui seems to be worthless, nothing I have tried will allow the network interface to be on automatically after boot.
- The server has Intel quad port NIC, only the first port has a LAN cable plugged into it and I just want this one port to be configured for wired networking.

At this point I do not care what the network interface name is.

All I want is for the server after boot for the wired network to connect automatically, for any and all users, for the static IPv4 address I tell it to use.  How do I either correct, or set up from scratch, the wired network configuration?  Please tell me as much as possible regarding wired network setup and configuration in rhel/centos 7.